# OnTriggerEnter2D dosn't work when player idle, but work when player moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in unity3d.

OnTriggerEnter2D can't work when player is idle, but whenever player move, OnTriggerEnter2D can work correctly.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

A rigidbody will sleep when its velocity is nearly 0. A quick fix is keeping the rigidbody awake by setting `sleepMode` to `NeverSleep` or calling `WakeUp` method every frame.

```
rigidbody.sleepMode = RigidbodySleepMode2D.NeverSleep;

if(rigidbody.IsSleeping())
    rigidbody.WakeUp();
```

But these approaches are not encouraged. A trigger is designed for being hitted by a rigidbody, so you'd better rethink your design. For instance if the trigger is a bullet, you can attach a `Rigidbody2D` on it and listen `OnCollisionEnter2D` callback.

Comment: thankyou! I solved it with your answer and the reason is my sword is not rigidbody.Your suggestion is very helpful